# Store curl command output in a variable in batch script

Tags: batch-file, curl

I tried many examples online, but was not able to make it work. I am new to this so please forgive my primitive question.

say I have this:

```
curl "www.google.com" -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n"
```

when running this in a cmd window, it returns the response code.

```
200
```

which is as expected.

I would like to do something like this in a batch script, but also use the output of the curl command to set a variable.
All examples I found online propose:

```
set res = $(curl "www.google.com" -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n")
echo %res%
pause
```

or like this

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`curl www.google.com -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n"`) DO ( SET var=%%F ) 
ECHO %var%
pause
```

both did not work, my batch script closes immediately.

Any feedback or help is highly appreciated
thank you.

Comment: To get the result of the command as a variable at the Command Prompt, you'd use `For /F %G In ('%__AppDir__%curl.exe -s -o NUL "https://www.google.com" -w "%{http_code}\n"') Do @Set "var=%G"`. If you want to do it in a batch file, then using the advice in the `for` command help information, `for /?`, which states "To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable.", you'd do it like this, `@For /F %%G In ('%__AppDir__%curl.exe -s -o NUL "https://www.google.com" -w "%%{http_code}\n"') Do @Set "var=%%G"`. _Note: I don't recommend using this domain for any reason_

Comment: In a batch file, the `%`-symbol in front of `{http_code}` need to be escaped by doubling it, like `%%{http_code}`…

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Compo, here is the formatted answer for other's benefit.

```
@echo off

For /F %%G In ('%__AppDir__%curl.exe -s -o NUL "www.google.com" -w "%%{http_code}\n"') Do Set "response=%%G"
echo response code is %response%

IF %response% == 200 (
    ECHO was able to ping google
) ELSE (
    ECHO unable to ping google
)

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

As he has mentionned above @Compo in his comment :

"To get the result of the command as a variable at the Command Prompt, you'd use `For /F`"

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Store curl command output in a variable in batch script
Set "MyCommand=curl "www.google.com" -o NUL -s -w "%%{http_code}""
@for /f %%R in ('%MyCommand%') do ( Set VAR=%%R )
echo %VAR% 
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your own answer code, there's no need to use a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) to get the result saved to a [variable](/questions/tagged/variable), and then compare that variable value with a known value. You can pipe the result through [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) to see if it matches your known value instead.

Example [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```
@%__AppDir__%curl.exe -s -o NUL "www.google.com" -w "%%{http_code}" ^
 | %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /X "200" 1> NUL && (Echo Ping Succeeded
) || Echo Ping Failed
@Pause
```

It is only really one line, split for readability, so you could do it line this in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```
%__AppDir__%curl.exe -s -o NUL "www.google.com" -w "%{http_code}" | %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /X "200" 1> NUL && (Echo Ping Succeeded) || Echo Ping Failed
```

Or like this as a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```
@(%__AppDir__%curl.exe -s -o NUL "www.google.com" -w "%%{http_code}" | %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /X "200" 1> NUL && (Echo Ping Succeeded) || Echo Ping Failed) & Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are good, but I would not use CURL to just test if we can reach a site:

```
@echo off
ping google.com -n 1 >nul 2>&1 
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
  echo EHHH..NO Google is not down, we are
) else (
  echo HURRAH MAN We are OK
)
```